# addChild is overlaying a MovieClip on the Stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, addchild

How do I make sure that a movie clip that starts on the stage has a higher zindex then when I addChild and add a linked movieClip from the library.

Really my code is pretty simple

```
background_image = new Sprite();
main_container.addChild (background_image);
```

But I have a movieClip "message_box" that I dragged onto the main timeline. When i add the background_image which is the full size of the stage it overlays the "message_box"

I know you can set the childs index but how do I set the "message_box" index?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your `message_box` to be on the highest layer, just use this:

```
if(message_box.parent)
    message_box.parent.addChild(message_box);
```

Most likely required whenever you use `addChild()` to add new elements to the stage.

Alternatively just make a container on a lower layer than the `message_box` and add all of your children into that.

Comment: So if everything else is added to the stage using new Sprite other then message_box will that still work? Thanks for the info. +1

Comment: Yep, if you use the above code everytime you add something new, the `message_box` will be placed onto the highest layer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container for all the MCs you would like to have above your background image

```
var background:Sprite = new Sprite();
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
var messageBox:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

addChild( background );

//will contain everything in between
addChild( container);

//The message will always be on top
addChild( messageBox );

//From then on, only use container to add children

var mc1:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
container.addChild( mc1 );
```